# Ошибка Assets\SceneManager.cs(10,16): error CS0117: 'SceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'LoadScene'

Tags: c#, unity3d

Много чего перепробывал 
Вот скрипт

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void game()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не стОит называть свои классы точно так же, как это названо в Юнити. Либо переименуйте свой класс в другой (и файл тоже), либо используйте полное имя класса, типа `UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(1);`  либо используйте алиасы ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive )

```
using unitySceneManager =  UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager;
...
...
... 
...
unitySceneManager.LoadScene(1);
```