# Ошибка "RectTransform" не содержит определения "sizeDelta"

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, разработка-игр

Пишу код для `Unity` и хочу, чтобы при активации скрипта объект UI менял свои размеры. Не могу понять, что не так. Вроде всё верно и должно работать, но не работает. [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не знаю, что делать, нужна помощь.

Comment: У тебя конфликт наименования, ты создал скрипт с именем, которое уже занято. О чём первое сообщение лога и говорит. Дай своему скрипту другое имя.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка Assets\SceneManager.cs(10,16): error CS0117: 'SceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'LoadScene'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1488858/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-assets-scenemanager-cs10-16-error-cs0117-scenemanager-does-not-cont)

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогли решить вопрос, всё дело в том, что я по глупости назвал свой скрипт (то есть класс) RectTransform  и из-за этого возникала ошибка.